# Haskell: 99 Questions #1: first solution doesn't run in GHCi

Tags: haskell

The first problem is to write a function to get the last element in a list.

The first solution provided in the solutions section is:

```
myLast :: [a] -> a
myLast [x] = x
myLast (_:xs) = myLast xs
```

So in GHCi I did:

```
Prelude> let myLast [a] = a
Prelude> let myLast (_:xs) = myLast xs
Prelude> myLast [1,2,3]
```

Which gave me the exception:

```
*** Exception: <interactive>:12:5-29: Non-exhaustive patterns in function myLast
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: I don't think you can enter function declarations in the interpreter like that. I think it's just remembering the most recent definition you gave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't working because your use of `let` in GHCi is wrong.

```
let myLast [a] = a
```

This defines a function `myLast` that only operates on lists of one element.

```
let myLast (_:xs) = mylast xs
```

This defines a new function, `myLast`, over-shadowing the old and unrelated function from the line above.  This new function throws an exception for any input (or fails to terminate).

You should enter:

```
:{
let myLast [x] = x
    myLast (_:xs) = myLast xs
:}
```

Or alternatively just enter your code in a file and not the repl.  I highly suggest you avoid the repl for anything beyond one-line or interactive experimentation.

Answer (score 3):

When you are using `let` in the interpreter, this is actually a let inside the `IO` monad, as for example in a do-block

```
do
  ...
  let x = ...
  ...
```

If you want to define a recursive function from inside *ghci* you can do

```
Prelude> :edit file.hs
```

Then the file `file.hs` will be opened in an editor (e.g., in *linux* the editor specified via the environment variable `EDITOR` will be chosen; in general you can set the used editor from inside *ghci* by `:set editor editor-name`; you can make this setting persistent by adding it to your `~/.ghci` file). Enter your function definition there. Save the file. And then load it in *ghci* with

```
Prelude> :load file.hs
```

Now the definitions from `file.hs` will be in scope.